# Python Snake colliding

Tags: python, pygame

i want to end my game than my snake collides with her body. But i just cant find a good solution for my code. I tryed to code it on my self, but everything was a fail. So maybe anyone from this community could give me advice how to do it?
Sorry for my english and poor code, i'm still newbie on this thing

```
import pygame,random

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#GameThings
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
bg_color = (0, 150, 0)
blue_color = (0, 0, 255)
red_color = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
fps = 60
score = 0
scoring = 10
direction = ""

#Snake
snake_x = 300
snake_y = 300
y_change = 0
x_change = 0
snake = pygame.Rect(snake_x, snake_y, 15, 15)
fruit = pygame.Rect(random.randint(50, 500), random.randint(50, 500), 10, 10)
snk_list = []
snk_lenght = 0


#Font
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)


def snake_colid():
    global score,scoring, snk_lenght
    if snake.colliderect(fruit):
        fruit.x = random.randint(30, 770)
        fruit.y = random.randint(30, 570)
        score += scoring
        snk_lenght += 5

def snake_grow():
    for x,y in snk_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue_color, [x, y, 15, 15])

def borders():
    if snake.x > 800:
        snake.x = 0
    if snake.x < 0:
        snake.x = 800
    if snake.y > 600:
        snake.y = 0
    if snake.y < 0:
        snake.y = 600





while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and direction != "down":
                y_change = -3
                x_change = 0
                direction = "up"
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and direction != "up":
                y_change = 3
                x_change = 0
                direction = "down"
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and direction != "right":
                x_change = -3
                y_change = 0
                direction = "left"
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and direction != "left":
                x_change = 3
                y_change = 0
                direction = "right"
                
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    
    if len(snk_list) > snk_lenght:
        del snk_list[0]

    head = []
    head.append(snake.x)
    head.append(snake.y)
    snk_list.append(head)

    #movement
    snake.x += x_change
    snake.y += y_change

    #Functions
    snake_colid()
    snake_grow()
    borders()

    #ScoreText
    text = font.render(str("Score: " + str(score)), True, blue_color)
    screen.blit(text, (30, 30))
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue_color, snake)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_color, fruit)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is there any exception?

Comment: After you calculate the new `head` see if that is in the list: `if head in snk_list: break`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find `pygame.groups` helpful just add `body object` to the pygame group and if the head collides with the any of body objects in the group you can kill the snake. You don't need to worry about body colliding with body since the head will always collide first